# QGIS 2.0: Automating tasks, text files and shapefiles

Tags: qgis, csv, text

Wondering if it's possible to automate some repetitive tasks in QGIS (2.0).

This is my general workflow for importing some xyz type text files from another software package which export (not overly efficient) fixed column data:

1. import fixed column text file into Excel
2. add fieldnames
3. create unique id field and populate using a combination (concatenate) of two fields in the existing data
4. remove null rows in between data groupings
5. remove unwanted columns
6. save to csv
7. import into QGIS
8. convert to polylines and save as shapefile

I'm thinking that this is achievable in QGIS alone via some scripting?

Example File:

[image: Example of point file]

So, I want to keep the first 4 columns (X,Y,ID,Value), delete the final column, remove the rows with text, and create a polyline shapefile based on a field which is a combination of the 3rd (ID) and 4th (Value) columns (e.g. 0_2000, 0_2100, 1_2100, etc)
.

Comment: All it is possible in PostgreSQL/PostGIS (from import text file to receive shapefile). Please provide sample of text file

Comment: If you know Python and PyQGIS, you can do everything in the Python console or with a script in Processing, without Excel

Comment: Thanks, silly question perhaps. How do I go about attached a file to a post?

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Images

Images can be added primarily by using the the editor toolbar button insert image toolbar button. This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online (through the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard. Alternatively, it can be input similarly to adding a link:

HTML <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">
Markdown ![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the post with an example of the type of data and a brief explanation of what I would like to be able to do in QGIS without fluffing around with Excel.

Comment: Adding a sample output text file would help.

Comment: Okay, again it's not obvious how to attach a text file? Thanks